# Connection refused when using Scrapy with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy with Selenium to scrape a page with dynamically generated javascript content (http://huati.weibo.com). I'm consistently getting a connection refused, but I'm not sure if its something I'm doing or the server itself (which is in China, so theres a possibility of some sort of firewall issue?).

What I'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 48, in run
    spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 48, in create
    return spcls(**spider_kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/data/sina_crawler/sina_crawler/spiders/sspider.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.selenium.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 197, in start
    result = self.get_string("getNewBrowserSession", start_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 231, in get_string
    result = self.do_command(verb, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line 220, in do_command
    conn.request("POST", "/selenium-server/driver/", body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception socket.error: error(111, 'Connection refused') in <bound method SeleniumSpider.__del__ of <SeleniumSpider 'SeleniumSpider' at 0x1e246d0>> ignored
```

My code:

```
  1 from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
  2 from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
  3 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  4 from scrapy.http import Request
  5 
  6 from selenium import selenium
  7 
  8 
  9 class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
 10         name = "SeleniumSpider"
 11         allowed_domains = ["weibo.com"]
 12         start_urls = ["http://huati.weibo.com/"]
 13 
 14         def __init__(self):
 15             CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
 16             self.verificationErrors = []
 17             self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://huati.weibo.com")
 18             self.selenium.start()
 19 
 20         def __del__(self):
 21             self.selenium.stop()
 22             print self.verificationErrors
 23             CrawlSpider.__del__(self)
 24 
 25         def parse(self, response):
 26             hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
 27 
 28             sel = self.selenium
 29             sel.open(response.url)
 30 
 31             time.sleep(2.5)
 32 
 33             sites = sel.get_text('//html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[@class="interest_topicR"]')
 34             print sites
```

For reference I'm following this sample code: http://snipplr.com/view/66998/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is most likely server-side behavior.  Have you been hitting their site with lots of requests?  I just got the page no problem with `urllib` (no JavaScript obviously) so I doubt they are using sophisticated methods to detect bots.

My guess is you made too many requests in a short period.  My way of handling this would be to catch the `ConnectionError` and then use `time.sleep(600)` to rest for a while.  Then retry the connection.  You can also count the number of times the `ConnectionError` is thrown and give up after 4 or 5 tries.  It looks something like this:

```
def parse(url, retry=0, max_retry=5):
    try:
        req = sel.open(url)
    except ConnectionError:
        if retry > max_retry: break
        logging.error('Connection error, resting...')
        time.sleep(100)
        self.parse(url, retry+1, max_retry)
```

Comment: I thought it was server-side at first too, but I'm now quite sure it's a problem with my code. Still stumped as to where though. I'm all but certain it's not due to making too many requests from their site, as I've only run the spider 15ish times so far and, currently, the script only loads a single page once.